# Calculating time taken for interprocess communication

Tags: c, linux

In Linux if I'm having two processes using C programs that can communicate with each other (via shm, socket, pipe or etc), how can I measure the time taken for the processes to communicate in C??

i.e. given processes A and B, with A sending the message and B, reading it and MB being some sort of a message box for communication, I wish to measure the time taken for A to put the message in MB and for B to retrieve the message from MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the time, e.g., the result of gettimeofday in to the message preamble, and use the time at the receiving end to measure the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In case of message queues, each message queue has an unique msg queue id. and has an associated data structure of type struct msquid_ds, defined in **,** containing the following members:

struct ipc_perm msg_perm;

```
   ushort msg_qnum;         /* no of messages on queue */

   ushort msg_qbytes;       /* bytes max on a queue */

   ushort msg_lspid;        /* pid of last msgsnd call */

   ushort msg_lrpid;        /* pid of last msgrcv call */

   time_t msg_stime;        /* last msgsnd time */

   time_t msg_rtime;        /* last msgrcv time */

   time_t msg_ctime;        /* last change time */
```

You can access **msg_stime** for last message send time and **msg_rtime** for last message receive time.